# Undefined reference in MinGW after moving from VC++

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, g++, mingw

I'm trying to compile my OpenGL shared library using g++ in MinGW but I get an error with undefined function reference.

I link all the necessary static libraries, but it doesn't work. Previously it was compiled via VC++, but after moving to MinGW it broke.

Could this be some kind of MinGW feature?

#### Error

```
Warning: resolving _GetModuleHandleA@4 by linking to _GetModuleHandleA
...
...
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `LoadLibraryA@4'
```

#### Compilation settings

```
g++ 
-g -Wall -shared
-IC:/Users/nikita/.jdks/corretto-11.0.22/include -IC:/Users/nikita/.jdks/corretto-11.0.22/include/win32
-LC:/Windows/System32
-lopengl32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lodbc32 -lodbccp32
-o artifact 
src/shared.h src/gl/shared-gl.h src/gl/windows.cpp
```

Comment: Why are you moving to an ancient GCC 6? The latest version is 13, you can get it from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-can-i-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2). And remove that `-LC:/Windows/System32`.

Comment: I'd put the `-l...` libraries at the end of the compile command line. [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: @RetiredNinja
This really solves the problem! Thank you! Could you write this in answer?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes